# Connect windows and linux containers running on the same host

Tags: docker, windows-container, linux-containers

I have a vanilla PostgreSQL Linux container running on a windows server, I also have a windows container running on the same windows server. For application purposes I have the windows container create and connect to an external NAT network because windows networks do not persist after restart of the server.

What I would like to do is be able to connect to the Linux container from my windows container. Unfortunately they seem to be on completely different subnets, and I cannot even ping one from the other. Is there a way to connect a windows container and Linux container on the same server?

Comment: Did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect them via published ports on the host.

I have a similar situation. Our layered application has 2 Windows (ASP.Net 4.8, SignalR, Hangfire and IIS) and 3 Linux (Nginx, Redis, Oracle 11 xe) containers running under WSL2. All of them are running smoothly in my 16Gb RAM notebook. Linux is interacting with Windows containers via published ports on my Windows 10 Pro.